# How to make git not show the deleted file list after I commit

Tags: git, github

[master +0 ~0 -1]> this is how my git repo looks after I comitted. the +0 ~0 -1 are all in red.

Q what does +0 ~0 -1 in red mean?
Q If that indicates a deleted file how do I remove that because I already comitted my changes i.e I want my repository to look like [master]

with git status I got this result

```
On branch master 
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. 
Changes not staged for commit: 
(use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed) 
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory) 
deleted: ClickForHelp/bin/classes/com/example/clickforhelp/controllers/MainActivity$GetLo‌​cationsAsyncTask.class 
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: with git status I got this result

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    ClickForHelp/bin/classes/com/example/clickforhelp/controllers/MainActivity$GetLocationsAsyncTask.cla
ss

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that might be -1 lines or something else, but to get to master, no matter where you are, you can use

`git reset --hard master`

Just be sure that you don't have anything that you don't mind losing.